# VBA copy sheets with macros

Tags: vba, excel

I have a series of Sheets in Excel which I'm coping to a new File. One of the Sheets has an object button that refers to a macro of the original file. On the new created file the button refers to the macro in the original file.

The code I use to transfer the Sheets is the following

```
Sheets(Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= "\\XXX\" & Filename & ".xlsb" _
    , FileFormat:=xlExcel12, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close
```

Is it possible to transfer the macros when copying the Sheets and refer the button to the new file?

Comment: You could do but you'd have to trust the vba project object model. Another  and simpler solution might be saving the whole workbook as a copy and deleting the sheets that aren't relevant? This would require a lot less code and keep your macros in tact.

Comment: What kind of button?  Forms or ActiveX ?

Comment: The button is an image (round circle with and i as for Information)

Comment: Your code shows you create a new workbook by copying the sheets - is the code contained in the sheet modules, or in regular modules in the source workbook?  Are you asking about how to also copy the code, or just about how to "repoint" the shape's "onaction" setting?

Comment: Tim, I would need both, to copy be code and make that the shape points to the code in the newly created file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try saving the whole workbok as a new file and delete the sheets you don't need. That way you keep the macro and the refrence in place. If the macro in the original file ties to itself by name ( `like workbooks(filename)` ) you should change that to `ThisWorkbook` or something similar dinamic reference in the original file.

Answer (score 1):

Put the code in the sheet(s) instead of a module and it will transfer to the new book.